# How to use result of join in Linq

Tags: linq, join, group-by

I have this SQL query and I want to use the same in Linq. I am confused as to how they use the group join alias in the main query?

```
SELECT '1st' AS POSITION , user as USR1, actiondate as ad1 , user2 as USR2, actiondate2 as ad2 ,user3 as USR3, actiondate3 as ad3, First as Co, * FROM APPLICATIONS A INNER  JOIN
    ( SELECT MAX(ROW) AS MAXDATE ,APPLICATIONNO FROM FIRSTM
    GROUP BY APPLICATIONNO) SULA1
    ON A.APPLICATIONNO=SULA1.APPLICATIONNO
    INNER JOIN FIRSTM FSTATUS
    ON SULA1.APPLICATIONNO=FSTATUS.APPLICATIONNO AND
    SULA1.MaxDate = FSTATUS.ROW
    INNER JOIN APPLICATIONAPPLICANTS ON A.APPLICATIONNO
     =APPLICATIONAPPLICANTS.APPLICATIONNO
```

Comment: You can write the Group Query as separate query and then use it in your query.

Comment: I have done the same but then I am not able to use the group query fields.  :(

Comment: I have seen this that no one answers this query whenever I ask. :D